# Compatible Javascript technologies for parse.com database

Tags: angularjs, node.js, backbone.js, express, parse-platform

We are planning to build a web app based on parse cloud database. We have confusion on choosing the right technology. The one thing we are sure about it is that we have to stick to parse.com as mobile app is using it.

The web app needs to be fast and should load most the content asynchronously or without reloading of page. The web app need to upload videos and images to parse cloud database and should be able to resize the images from client side( or some backend like node.js). So, we came up with the following options, but not sure which one is perfect for us.

1. Node.js + Express.js + EJS(or any other templating engine) + parse js sdk for node.js.
   In this case, we are not sure if we can achieve the desktop like UX.
2. Node.js(rest api) + Express.js +  Angular in frontend + parse js sdk for node.js . I am aware that if we are using angular, then we will have to code as per angular way or use $apply and digest loop(not 100% sure).
3. MEAN + parse js sdk for node: No idea how does it work.
4. Javascript framework + parse js sdk(no backend): Here, not sure if we should go with Backbone or Angular or any other. We have some knowledge of Angular but completely oblivious to Backbone.
5. Meteor + parse js sdk for node.js: Meteor updates on client if database changes. Not sure, if it can work with parse cloud database in same way.

Please share your views on it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused about what Parse platform offers. Parse is a Mobile Backend As a Service(MBaaS) not a Database As a service (DBaaS). They have done most of the work for you so that you do not need to tinker much with the technology on the server side of things so you can focus mostly on the frontend. If you are basically trying to build a web app frontend for a project which is utilising Parse as its backend, you should embrace Parse solution completely.

For building a web app frontend, Parse offers their Javascript SDK which is based on `Backbone.js`. If you want to go down the `Angular.js` route, then you need to get your hands dirty and do some extra work to get it to work. Thankfully others have tried this before so you are not alone. For example check [this](https://github.com/EnolaLabs/Angular-Parse-Repositories) project

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did not misunderstood the parse. Using it through Javascript API in frontend will end up in exposing the keys. So, if keys are exposed, the ACL and CLP(class level permissions) needs to be perfect.

Comment: Parse js sdk can be used with node.js as per the link: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-javascript-sdk-in-node-js/

So, we may consider using express.js with node.js or MEAN. I hope, I am more clear now.

Comment: Parse application keys should be treated as if they are public(except for the Master key), so the desire to somehow hide them from a malicious user means that you are not thinking about securing your Parse application as recommended by Parse. Sure, you can run Parse SDK on Node but you somehow need to be able to justify the work and overhead involved for example if you plan to implement something where Parse is lacking like a real-time chat system. At the end the choice is yours.